# XSLT-Check if child node has value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have input xml roughly in below format.

```
<Root>
       <PAF>
         <Child1 xsi:nil="true" />
         <Child2 xsi:nil="true" />
         <Child3>BlahBlah</Child3>
       </PAF>
   </Root>
```

While transforming it into XML, I wanted to check 
if `<PAF>` has any child having value (in my case it is `<Child3>`)
then do something.
If all child have nil="true"
then do something

I am bit new for XSLT scripting, So far I could get only count of child node of `<PAF>`.
Can some one please suggest me the if-else syntax in my context?
Do I need any XPATH expression here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1. Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 (or 3.0)? - 2. What exactly is that "something" you want to do?

Comment: It would be XSLT 1.0
I wanted to display <Child3> as <TransformedChild3> 
Over all block will look like :

<TransformedPAF>
<TransformedChild3>BlahBlah</TransformedChild3>
<TransformedPAF>

If no child has value, block of <TransformedPAF> will not be there in output xml

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise about what "having value" means. Consider cases like `<Child3/>`, `<Child4><x/></Child4>`, `<Child5><!--comment--></Child5>`, `<Child6 status='3'/>`.

Comment: It would be always in the form of <Child3>BlahBlah</Child3>  (and if not then <Child3 xsi:nil="true" />)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are in the context of `PAX`, you could so something like:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="*[not(@xsi:nil='true')]">
        <!-- not all chiLd nodes are empty -->
        <!-- DO SOMETHING HERE -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- all child nodes are empty -->
        <!-- DO SOMETHING ELSE -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

If there is no DO SOMETHING ELSE, then use `xsl:if` instead of `xsl:choose`.

---

Note that the `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declaration must be present in both your XML and XSLT documents.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.Somehow it is not detecting all 'nil' childs

Comment: I said "*Assuming you are in the context of `PAX`*". You are in the context of `Location`.

Comment: Yes, Mine context was wrong..Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xsi="www.nill.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PAF">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!--Checked no data inside PAF and its descendants and not other attributes other than xsi:nill then Drop.--> 
            <xsl:when test="(count(descendant-or-self::*/@*[not(name() = 'xsi:nil')]) = 0) and (not(normalize-space()))"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!